# Sort by ID filtering by date interval DynamoDB

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I want to be able to filter items in a table given a date interval, and still sort the results by their IDs.

I understand I could use the `between` operation in the SK to query the dates, although, this creates the constraint of not allowing the results to be sorted by the item ID. Considering the following GSI scheme:

```
gsi_1 : {
  "pk": { "item_type" }
  "sk": { date }
}
```

My query to get the items contained in a date interval would look like:

```
"IndexName": "Gsi1Index",
"KeyConditionExpression": "gsi_1_pk = :item_type and gsi_1_sk between :date_start and :date_end"
```

Is it possible to still sort the results by ID?

I'm not attached to any specific GSI scheme, any new modeling ideas to allow such query are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

DynamoDB will return results sorted by your sort key.  If you want to change that, you'll need to redefine your sort key or perform the sorting in your application code.

Although it's not clear from your question, you *might* have stumbled across a good use-case for KSUIDs.

A KSUID, or K-Sortable Unique Identifier, is a unique identifier with time-based ordering.  This lets you have unique identifiers that are sortable by creation time (or another time if needed).  You can read a [Brief history of the UUID](https://segment.com/blog/a-brief-history-of-the-uuid/) for more details.

KSUIDs are great when you have a need for unique ID's *and* time sorting.  I've found it especially useful in DynamoDB where I often have the need to sort by creation date.

There are KSUID libraries in several programming languages, so you don't need to implement the algorithm yourself.  There's even a [KSUID generator website](https://golang.cafe/ksuid) that you can use to quickly interact with KSUIDs.

Comment: Hey @Seth, I don't want to sort items by any date/time. I want to **Filter** items by a date interval, but **Sort** them by the item's ID. KSUID seems not an option here. Correct me please if I missed something.

Comment: Hi @andreybleme.  DynamoDb implements sorting using the sort key only.  You will not be able to sort by ID, regardless of what your filter looks like.  Whatever attribute you want to sort by needs to be incorporated into the sort key *or* be sorted in your application code.

Comment: It occurs to me that you did not include the details of your main table, only the GSI.  I don't see an "ID" field anywhere in your example.  Where is the ID attribute and what does it look like?